# Why does Lightroom only recognise my lens after I set the make?

Tags: lightroom, lightroom-5

I have a Tamron 70-300 and use Lightroom 5. When I process photos taken with any of my other lenses, and enable Lens Correction, Lightroom automatically detects the lens make and model. However, when I process photos taken with the Tamron, it doesn't. I have to select the make, and *then* it automatically recognises the focal length etc.

Why is this and can anything be done about it? As far as I can recall it did this in LR 4 as well.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with exactly the same lens. No idea, why the manufacturer could not find a more distinctive string for this lens model.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Lenses have different identification strings depending on how well the camera can identify the lens.

For example a Canon lens on an Canon camera may be identified in the EXIF information as `EF24-70mm f/2.8L USM`, while a Sigma lens on the same camera may be identified as just `50-500mm`.

The first one can be identified to the exact lens model, while the second one might match several lenses. When the identification string in the EXIF info doesn't contain enough information, you have to choose the make to narrow it down enough for Lightroom to be able to pick out the single model.

Comment: This seems not reasonable to me, because in my case (Sigma 24-105 f/4) the make is absolutely and clearly written in the EXIF metadata.